# Is it possible to close uTorrent when the downloads are finished?

Tags: windows-7, utorrent

I'm using the latest version of uTorrent on Windows 7 64bit.

Is it possible to close uTorrent when the downloads are finished?

Comment: It is generally a good idea to accept an answer if it answers your question. If your question is still unresolved, just post here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Options->autoshutdown->quit when downloads complete.

Answer (score 8):

Its quite easy as I've take a screen shot for you take  a look on it. There are many option available for you.

[image]